# Error related to conditional statement in the code

Tags: python

I am trying to perform traceback for my matrix,which should follow the steps as shown in image as shown in this [link](http://assignmentpytshome.blogspot.com). My answer is just providing one value -  `7` whereas there should be two more values as answer - `1,4`.
Here is the traceback method:

1) Read the last row of the matrix,if the element is less than or equal to 1 and not equal to zero; we consider it for our traceback.

2) Then,we check the adjacent diagonal,vertical and horizontal values of that element,and if the value at `M[i,j]` against any of three `(M[i-1,j]+1,M[i,j-1]+1,M[i-1,j-1]+1)` conditions.

3)
a) If `M[i,j] = M[i-1,j]+1` we go vertically up to next element and consider it as our next `M[i,j]`.
b) If `M[i,j]=M[i,j-1]+1` we go horizontally to next element and consider as our next `M[i,j]`
c) If `M[i,j]` is equal to both `M[i,j-1]+1` and `M[i-1,j]+1`,we prefer to go vertically up to choose our next `M[i,j]`.

4) If there `i+1,j+1` belong to tuple list,then we follow these conditions:
a) If `M[i,j] = M[i-1,j]+1` we go vertically up to next element and consider it as our next `M[i,j]`
b) If `M[i,j]=M[i,j-1]+1` we go horizontally to next element and consider as our next `M[i,j]`.
c) If `M[i,j]=M[i-1,j-1]`, then we go diagonally and choose our next `M[i,j]`.
d) If there is possibility to go diagonally or vertically,we prefer to go diagonally in this case,as there is match. We continue like this till we reach the 1st row,and then return the corresponding `j` position.

```
  def test():


    M=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],[2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
    positions = [(1, 4), (1, 7), (2, 2), (2, 5)]
    list=[]
    k=1
    for i in range(2,-1,-1):
        for j in range(7,-1,-1):
            if M[2][j]<=1 and M[2][j]!=0:#checking last row for tracing back
                if (i+1,j+1) not in positions:
                    if M[i][j]== M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j-1]+1:#move horizontally
                        j -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    elif M[i][j]!= M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j-1]+1:
                        i -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    elif M[i][j]== M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j-1]+1:#
                        j -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    elif M[i][j]== M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j-1]+1:
                        i -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    elif M[i][j]!= M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j-1]+1:
                        i -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    elif M[i][j]== M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j-1]+1:
                        j -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    else :
                        print "error"

            elif (i+1,j+1) in positions:
                    if M[i][j]== M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j-1]:
                        j -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    elif M[i][j]!= M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j-1]:
                        i -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    elif M[i][j]!= M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j-1]:#
                        j -= 1
                        i -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)

                    elif M[i][j]== M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j-1]:
                        i -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    elif M[i][j]!= M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j-1]:
                        i -= 1
                        j -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)

                    elif M[i][j]== M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]!=M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j-1]:
                        j -= 1
                        i -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    elif M[i][j]== M[i][j-1]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j]+1 and M[i][j]==M[i-1][j-1]:
                        j -= 1
                        i -= 1
                        if i==0:
                            list.append(j+1)
                    else :
                        print "error"

            else:
                pass
    return list

print(test())
```

Comment: You know that `range(2,0,-1)` excludes `0`, right?  If you want to include it, you need `range(2,-1,-1)`.  Similarly for `range(7,0,-1)`

Comment: Thank you.I modified.But it is showing same error.

Comment: I made a quick attempt to run your examples, but it contains errors that prevent it.  In the assignment to `M` the sub-lists are missing comma separators (syntax error).  If that error is fixed, it gets to the bottom and gives an error that `text` is undefined.  Can't run it.

Comment: There's also an argument mismatch between the definition of `trace` (2 args) and the invocation (4 args).  Please make sure your example is complete and does what you claim before posting.

Comment: I have modified it and the example is giving the result my program has been giving me.

Comment: I was able to get it to run this time.  It prints `error` 11 times, then it prints `[7, 7]`.  The problem I have is I don't really understand what this is supposed to do, even after looking at the white board notes you posted.

Comment: All those notes should be formatted into the question, not written as comments.  Please fix!  When you've done that, you can delete your comments and flag this for deletion (it will be obsolete when you've done your job).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be straight with you, that code is real ugly. Try writing your method using this class NavMat, this should protect of from indexing errors in your conditionals.

```
class NavMat():
    mat = []
    row = 0
    col = 0
    width = 0
    height = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.mat.append([])
    # Initialize an empty 2x2 matrix
    def set(self,a):
        self.mat = a
        self.width = len(a[0])
        self.height = len(a[1])
    def at(self,x,y):
        self.row = x
        self.col = y
        return(self.mat[x][y])
    # retruns element at x,y and sets row and column accordingly
    def north(self):
        if (self.row>0):
            return(self.mat[self.row-1][self.col])
        else:
            return(None)
    # Returns value north of current position (one row up*)
    def south(self):
        if (self.row<self.height):
            return(self.mat[self.row+1][self.col])
        else:
            return(None)
    # Returns value south of current position (one row down*)
    def east(self):
        if (self.col<self.width):
            return self.mat[self.row][self.col+1]
        else:
            return(None)
    # Returns value east of current position (one column right*)
    def west(self):
        if (self.col>0):
            return(self.mat[self.row][self.col-1])
        else:
            return(None)
    # Returns value west of current position (one column left*)
    def northEast(self):
        if(self.row>0 and self.col<self.width):
            return(self.mat[self.row-1][self.col+1])
        else:
            return(None)
    # Up and to the right
    def southEast(self):
        if(self.row<self.height-1 and self.col<self.width):
            return(self.mat[self.row+1][self.col+1])
        else:
            return(None)
    # down and to the right
    def southWest(self):
        if(self.row<self.height - 1 and self.col>0):
            return(self.mat[self.row+1][self.col-1])
        else:
            return(None)
    # Down and to the left
    def northWest(self):
        if(self.row>0 and self.col>0):
            return(self.mat[self.row-1][self.col-1])
        else:
            return(None)
    # Up and to the left
    def prt(self):
        s = ""
        for k in self.mat:
            s+="\n"
            for k2 in k:
                s+=str(k2)+"\t"
        print(s)
    #Prints the matrix
m = NavMat()
```

Classes like this are a little bit of overhead but they make writing the remaining code significantly less miserable (especially if you ever have to come back and read it later, or ask questions on stack overflow).